# How to prove with Taylor-theorem that if $f$ and $f''$ are bounded, than $f'$ is bounded, too?

Tags: functions, derivatives, taylor-expansion

$f:R→R$ is twice differentiable. $f$ and $f''$ are bounded. How to prove with Taylor-theorem that $f'$ is bounded as well?

Comment: What's restricted?

Comment: What does "resctricted function" mean here?

Comment: Do you mean "bounded"?

Comment: yeah, sorry, I mean bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x$, by Taylors theorem,
$$f(x+1) = f(x) + f^\prime (x) + \frac{1}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)$$

for some $\xi\in (x, x+1)$. Now solve for $f^\prime(x)$.

Comment: smart solution! :)